# Linux: what is the most efficient way of reading a file from a NAS and sending over a socket

Tags: linux, performance, sockets, nas

I would like to write a server that reads in a file from a NAS and sends it out over
a socket. What is the fastest way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Many more details required. :) Are you doing this for one file at a time? Or should your server be [c10k-ready](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html)? Can you just use `nginx` or Apache `httpd` and be done with it? _Maybe_ a simple standard `while(1) { select() ...}` loop would work, but `read(2)` calls on the NAS might block if the NAS is heavily loaded or network goes kaputt -- in which case, maybe the `aio.h(7posix)` (`aio_read(3)`) routines would be a better choice. Not sure which NAS filesystems support AIO, if any. More details! :D

Comment: Thanks, sarnold. I need a custom server to serve jpeg2000 compressed files over UDP socket. It needs to scale. AIO sounds like a good idea. Its likely that I will need to use CIFS to access NAS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need advice on writing a simple LInux file server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005647/need-advice-on-writing-a-simple-linux-file-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* standard CIFS mounts support `mmap(2)` on the files (if I read correctly, [`direct` mode](http://www.kernel.org/doc/readme/fs-cifs-README) must be off).

If so, your fastest option is probably to `open(2)` files as normal, and use `sendfile(2)` to send the file data over your UDP sockets. (`sendfile(2)` requires the file to mappable, which isn't always guaranteed, but the CIFS client code in the kernel (`fs/cifs/file.c:cifs_file_strict_mmap()`) appears to support `mmap(2)`.)

[Pat Patterson reports an 8% speedup with `sendfile(2)` vs `write(2)`](http://blog.superpat.com/2010/06/01/zero-copy-in-linux-with-sendfile-and-splice/). But if it works, it'd save you the hassle of handling AIO operations yourself -- the kernel would be in charge of requesting memory pages from the file, sending them over the socket when the socket buffers allow, and hopefully allow your application code to be short and sweet.

Comment: awesomesauce! thanks, sarnold. I like this approach, being a little obsessed with performance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your network interfaces on both sides are 1Gbit ethernet or slower, just do anything you like. Your machine will be able to fill them up.

Comment: Thanks, MarkR. By fast, I mean requiring the least CPU, rather than network throughput. So, sendfile would be better in this case.

Comment: By "fast", I mean requiring the least developer-time to produce a correct implementation. According to moore's law, if you wait two months, hardware will be 8% faster for the same price anyway. Is that 8% performance (cited by @sarnold) important enough to you to sacrifice a correct implementation (not using sendfile, etc) ?